# How to get group info like (owner,participants etc) in nodejs using whatsapp-web.js

Tags: node.js, whatsapp

This is my code

```
const chats = await client.getChats();
const groupChats = chats.filter((chat) => chat.isGroup);
```

There is a method called [`new GroupChat()`](https://docs.wwebjs.dev/GroupChat.html) in whatsapp-web.js.
This method gives the group.

How can I use that method if I have `chats` array?

Comment: in Simple Words I want only those group in which i am the admin or only i have the permission to add messages in the groups

Answer (score 0):

new GroupChat will not give you group client.getchats will give you all the chats including groups. you will then filter and then map yout groups after that use new groupchat like given below to perform functions on that group hope this will help you if not let me know your question thorougly.

```
import GroupChat from "whatsapp-web.js/src/structures/GroupChat.js";
  
const ch = await client.getChatById(group.gid._serialized);
console.log("chat here", ch);
let gr = new GroupChat(client, ch);

console.log("groupchat", gr);
await gr.sendMessage("Group Chat");
```

Comment: in Simple Words i want only those group in which i am the admin or only i have the permission to add messages in the groups

Comment: Use library Api, here is owner property https://docs.wwebjs.dev/GroupChat.html#owner

Comment: how can i use this .. i know this already .. but i dont know how to use this GroupChat() , if i have an array of all chats

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to cast the chat into a group chat if you know it's a group chat; which you already have a check in the `isGroup` property

```
const chatObjects = chats.filter((chat) => chat.isGroup);
```

Now you have chats you regard as groups (but still as chat objects)

```
const groupChats = chatObjects.map((groupChat) => {
  // Cast each chat to a GroupChat type 
  const groupChatObj = groupChat as GroupChat;
  return groupChatObj;
});
```

Now that you have the group chats, it's time to look through the participants of each group and check if they are admins. Then check your own user id against that list to see if you are an admin.

```
const adminInGroupChats = groupChats.filter((groupChat) => {
  const admins = groupChat.participants.filter((participant) => participant.isAdmin);
  const isMeAdmin = admins.some((admin) => admin.userId === MY_USER_ID);
  return isMeAdmin;
});
```

Just replace 'MY_USER_ID' with your actual user id.

I generally don't like having to think about nested arrow functions; but I can't deny the elegance.